# Plot sklearn's DecisionBoundaryDisplay for Classifier With More Than 2 Features

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn, classification

### Observation

There are [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76876844/color-regions-in-a-scatter-plot/76877301#76877301) using the [iris dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html) of how to plot decision boundaries using [`sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay.html#sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay) on a model trained on only 2 (arbitrary) features out of 4 available. Of course that is not the classifier I want to end up with, since I want to include all 4 features into the model.

However, when including all features `DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator` raises

> ValueError: Input X contains NaN.
>
> KNeighborsClassifier does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively....

The documentation describes the signature of `DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(estimator, X, ...)` where `X` is said to be *of shape (n_samples, 2). Input data that should be only 2-dimensional.*

But obviously it need not only be 2-dimensional, but have only 2 features.

I also tried to train the model on all features, but pass only 2 of them to `from_estimator`, which raises:

> ValueError: X has 2 features, but RobustScaler is expecting 4 features as input.

### Question

Is there any way of plotting a 2-d intersection of the decision boundary of a higher dimensional model?

### Code Example

This is based on sklearn's [Classifier Comparison](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html) article

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.inspection import DecisionBoundaryDisplay
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler


iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

classifiers = {
    "KNN": KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5),
    "RBF SVM": SVC(kernel="rbf"),
}

intersections = [
    ["sepal length (cm)", "sepal width (cm)"],
    ["petal length (cm)", "petal width (cm)"],
]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(classifiers), len(intersections),
                        figsize=(4 * len(intersections), 4 * len(classifiers)))

for i, (name, mdl) in enumerate(classifiers.items()):
    clf = make_pipeline(RobustScaler(), mdl)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    for j, cols in enumerate(intersections):
        sns.scatterplot(X_test, x=cols[0], y=cols[1], hue=y_test, ax=axs[i, j])
        DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(clf, X, alpha=0.2, ax=axs[i, j])
```

Comment: Don't you have missing values? ValueError: Input X contains NaN. you need to fill them somehow

Comment: Checked it for every row and column. Not a single NaN-value. The exception message really is misleading.